# Sigma algebra proof

Tags: measure-theory

On page 54 of [these notes](http://www.maths.univ-evry.fr/pages_perso/jeanblanc/conferences/lisbon.pdf) (section 3.3)
the following property of the sigma algebras is stated.

> Let:
>   $H_t = 1_{\tau \leqslant t}$ (where $\tau$ and $H_t$ are random variables on some probability space, $1_A$ is indicator on A); $\mathcal{H}_t = \sigma(H_s : s \leq t)$ - the sigma algebra generated by all the $H_s$ for $s\leqslant t$,
>   $\mathcal{F}$ is another sigma algebra.

Then for any set $A$ in $\sigma(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{H}_t)$, $A \cap \{ \tau > t\} = F\cap \{ \tau > t\}$ for some $F$ in $\mathcal{F}$.

This seems intuitive, but I'm struggling to give a really rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1):

We can follow the following strategy:

1. the collection of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ for which there exists $F\in\mathcal F$ such that $A\cap \{\tau>t\}=F\cap\{\tau>t\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
2. It contains both $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal H_t$.

Comment: That's a very neat argument! Many thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.